# Getting integer from array as a separate variable in python

Tags: python, arrays, variables, assign

I'm trying to find an images x and y coordinates using opencv which seems to work fine. But I only want to return one x and y and not the entire array which the opencv function creates. This is how I'm trying to do it:

```
def getImageXY():
    im = pyautogui.screenshot()
    im.save(filePathSrc)

    img_rgb = cv2.imread(filePathSrc)
    template = cv2.imread(filePathToFind)

    res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_rgb, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
    threshold = .8

    loc = np.where(res >= threshold)

    x = loc[1]
    y = loc[0]

    return x, y
```

And this is where I'm trying to assign the values

```
def main():
    x, y = ImageFinder.getImageXY()

    print x, y
```

My expected output is "322, 766" (simply two separate single x and y values)

But this is my actual output :
    [313 502 314 503 296 485 297 470 486 298 471 487 267 299 472 488 300 473
     489 474 490 475]

I.e the entire array.

What am I doing wrong? Doing the exact same thing in java would work as I expect it to but not in python...

Any guesses?

Thanks

Comment: fix your indentation

Comment: It is indented correctly, it's just that it didn't show in the post

Comment: Any change your `loc` is 2-dimensional?

Comment: You could just run your lines manually, starting with the ```cv2.imread```-s, and see what ```loc``` happens to contain at the end. It is pretty obvious that there can be more than one pixels satisfying the condition. Reading the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) may be a good idea too.

Comment: @Colin you were right, it was 2d. What's weird is that it concatenated the both arrays when I printed it, so in my output stated above 313 was the correct x and 502 was the correct y value. So I just assumed it stored the coords [x,y,x,y] and so on... Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Cool, I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `loc` is 2-dimensional, which is causing the effect you're seeing.